# multi language website poEDit and getText()

Tags: php, multilingual

I am trying to create a new multilanguage website.  I use `poEDit` and `getText()` function.  I don't know what I have missed with this code:

```
<?php
    if (!function_exists("gettext"))
    { 
       echo "gettext is not installed\n";
    } else  { 
       echo "gettext is supported\n"; 
    }

    $language = 'ar_JO';
    putenv("LANG=$language"); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

    $domain = 'ar_JO';
    bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale");
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
    textdomain($domain);

    echo _("HELLO_WORLD");
    echo _("hi this to be translated ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory is very imported. Create a directory structure like this:

```
locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messages_de_DE.mo
locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messages_de_DE.po
```

Then try this example code:

```
<?php

$locale = 'de_DE';
//$locale = 'fr_CH';
$domain = 'messages';
$codeset = 'UTF-8';
$directory = __DIR__ . '/locale';

// Activate the locale settings
putenv('LC_ALL=' . $locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

// Debugging output 
$file = sprintf('%s/%s/LC_MESSAGES/%s_%s.mo', $directory, $locale, $domain, $locale);
echo $file . "\n";

// Generate new text domain
$textDomain = sprintf('%s_%s', $domain, $locale);

// Set base directory for all locales
bindtextdomain($textDomain, $directory);

// Set domain codeset (optional)
bind_textdomain_codeset($textDomain, $codeset);

// File: ./locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messages_de_DE.mo
textdomain($textDomain);

// test translations
echo _('Yes');
```

Comment: I have got this " C:\wamp\www\loginSystemOOP/locale/ar_JO/LC_MESSAGES/messages_ar_JO.mo "


and my file structure is 'C:\wamp\www\loginSystemOOP/locale/ar_JO/LC_MESSAGES/'